# Visual Studio 2010 with SP1 installer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, service-pack

Is there an installer for Visual Studio 2010 that includes service pack 1, or maybe a way to make it manually (e.g. service pack for windows can be embedded into original rtm installer)?

Comment: Maybe these links here help you: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (Installer)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5) [Description of Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509)

Comment: This is not installer for Visual Studio only for sp. You still have to install Visual Studio b4 you can use this

Comment: Are you want visual studio 2010 pack link?.